# XmlHttpRequest set status

Tags: java, javascript, android, ajax

I want to handle all Ajax request by the following method:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send=function(body){
  var myResponse='myResponse';
  Object.defineProperty(this,'responseText',{
    get:function(){
      return res
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this,'readyState',{
    get:function(){
       return 4
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this,'status',{
     get:function(){
       return 200
    }
  });
  this.onreadystatechange();
};
```

In the output, responseText and readyState are successfully being what I want. However Chrome gives me this error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'status' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': the object's state must not be OPENED.

I know I need to set the readyState to 200 so that the other parts of the webpage can run without exceptions. But I don't know why I can't set it in this way and how I can do it. Any ideas would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you trying to emulate AJAX or actually send a request to the server?

Comment: @serakfalcon It is difficult to explain... Maybe you should suppose that I am dropping all requests (myResponse='')

Comment: what I mean is, typically if you were using an AJAX request, the response would come back from the server, and so javascript would not be setting these values at all, rather just reading them and checking to see if they are what you want or not. It's a different story if you're just trying to emulate the request however.

Comment: It's an Android application. JS will ask Java to load the request. Then Java will send the loaded data back to JS. The data will become myResponse.